# Integration of $\cos^2(x)$ detailed

Tags: calculus, integration

I already found the answer which was $(\cos(x)\sin(x)+ x)/2 + C$
but I don't know where that came from, it also shows the before integration it has been changed into $(\cos(x)\sin(x))/2 + 1/2$ but didn't know where that came from too.

Comment: Do you know the power reducing formula?  Do you know integration by parts?

Comment: Use $\cos^2(x)=\frac12(1+\cos(2x))$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hints/ Ingredients needed:

$$\cos(2x)= 2\cos^2(x)-1$$

$$\int \cos(x) dx= \sin(x)+C$$

$$\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x) \cos(x)$$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\cos^2 (x)&=\left(\frac {e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}\right)^2\\
&=\frac {1}{4}(e^{2ix}+2+e^{-2ix})\\
&=\frac {1+\cos (2x)}{2}
\end{align*}

The antiderivative is then

\begin{align*}
\frac {1}{2}\int (1+\cos (2x))\,dx&=\frac {x}{2}+\frac {1 }{4}\sin (2x)+C\\
&=\frac {x}{2}+\frac {1}{2}\sin (x)\cos (x)+C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Using the power reducing formula:

The power reducing formula for $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$.  Therefore,
$$
\int\cos^2(x)dx=\int\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}dx=\int\frac{1}{2}dx+\int\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}dx.
$$
Using the $u$-substitution $u=2x$ so $du=2dx$ (or $\frac{1}{2}du=dx$) on the second integral gives
$$
\frac{1}{2}x+\int\frac{\cos(u)}{4}du=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin(u)+C=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+C.
$$
Then, using the double angle formula, we get that this equals
$$
\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)\cos(x)+C.
$$

Using integration by parts:

Using integration by parts, we take $u=\cos(x)$ and $dv=\cos(x)dx$.  Then, 
\begin{align*}
u&=\cos(x)&dv&=\cos(x)dx\\
du&=-\sin(x)dx&v&=\sin(x)
\end{align*}
Then,
$$
\int\cos^2(x)dx=\sin(x)\cos(x)-\int-\sin^2(x)dx=\sin(x)\cos(x)+\int\sin^2(x)dx.
$$
Then, using the trigonometric identity $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$ or rather $\sin^2(x)=1-\cos^2(x)$, we get
$$
\int\cos^2(x)dx=\sin(x)\cos(x)+\int1-\cos^2(x)dx=\sin(x)\cos(x)+\int1dx-\int\cos^2(x)dx=\sin(x)\cos(x)+x-\int\cos^2(x)dx.
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
\int\cos^2(x)dx=\sin(x)\cos(x)+x-\int\cos^2(x)dx.
$$
If we take this and add $\int\cos^2(x)dx$ to both sides, we get
$$
2\int\cos^2(x)dx=\sin(x)\cos(x)+x+C.
$$
Here, we need to add a $+C$ to the RHS because our answer could differ by a constant and we don't have a constant on the RHS when we get rid of $\int\cos^2(x)dx$.  Anyway, dividing both sides by $2$ gives
$$
\int\cos^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\sin(x)\cos(x)+\frac{1}{2}x+C'
$$
where $C'=\frac{1}{2}C$ is just another constant.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following idea, using $\;\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1\;$ ?:

$$x=\int 1dx=\int(\cos^2x+\sin^2x)dx=\int\cos^2x\,dx+\int\sin^2x\,dx\;\;(**)$$

And now doing by parts:

$$\begin{cases}u=\sin x,&u'=\cos x\\{}\\v'=\sin x,&v=-\cos x\end{cases}\implies\int\sin^2x\,dx=-\cos x\sin x+\int\cos^2x\,dx$$

and we finally get:

$$(**)=\int\cos^2x\,dx-\cos x\sin x+\int\cos^2x\,dx\implies$$

$$2\int\cos^2x\,dx=x+\cos x\sin x\implies\int\cos^2x\,dx=\frac12\left(x+\cos x+\sin x\right)$$

...and don't forget the constant.:)